# Uri типа "pack" в Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, потоки-данных, resources

У меня есть консольное приложение с подключённой сборкой `PresentationCore`(тесты делаются здесь - так проще; проверял в оконном приложении и результаты одинаковы) и с вот таким классом `Program`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO.Packaging;

namespace MyApp
{
    using static WebRequest;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            RegisterPrefix("pack", new PackWebRequestFactory()); // префикс регистрируется (можно увидеть в режиме отладки)

            var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resource.resx");

            using (var client = new WebClient())
            using (var stream = client.OpenRead(uri)) // ошибка - не удалось найти файл resource.resx
            {
                // Using stream...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Файл `Resource.resx` существует и путь совпадает (если заменить `.resx` на `.xaml` и использовать `ResourceDictionary`, то файл находит, что странно (вылетит ошибка из-за "неугодного" содержания, но это не важно - файл находит)). Мне это нужно для одной библиотеки, там есть немного "low-левела", связанного с ресурсами и uri. Я копался в рефлекторе (класс `ResourceDictionary`) и всё вроде тоже самое, только с `.xaml` файлами. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: какую проблему то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resx должен иметь тип embedded resource. Для этого заходим в обозреватель решения, находим ваш  ресурс, свойства, делать при сборке - встроенный ресурс.

Comment: Я уже нашел решение: нужно было указать ещё и сборку. Пример с MSDN:
`pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;v1.0.0.1;component/ResourceFile.xaml`